# Is there a way to view the effective Spring properties for a given profile?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

With Spring (Boot), is there some way or tool to provide a profile or list of profiles and see what the resultant properties are? Before deploying to production, we'd like to verify that all our various properties will be as expected for that environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the spring boot actuator for viewing configuration properties amongst many other things that is made available from this plugin.

endpoint: /actuator/health/configprops

You can find all details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints)

Comment: That still requires a running application. I'd like to be able to collect the info before deploying to production.

Comment: Make sure you have the added the "spring-boot-starter-actuator" dependency in pom and in order to test, set the property management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=* in application.properties
This should let all endpoints be accessible, but make sure you expose only the ones needed in production because this will also provide information to the heap and memory dumps, which are useful, but should only be used by authorized members.

Comment: Yes, I used it in my dev environment, but that shows the properties for the dev environment. I want to see the properties for prod *before* deploying there.

Comment: Usually, the process is to move it to a staging environment that simulates a PROD environment, where you perform the tests that you mention before moving to PROD. I can not think of another automated way to satisfy your requirement.

Comment: However, exposing these endpoints will allow your team as well as DevOps to troubleshoot/check any app in PROD environment. It always good practice to utilize actuator plugin in any spring app. 

The other option is to make use of profiles and write test junit cases to test the value of the properties when your profile is set to PROD.